# Why is my state not reflecting immediate in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know I'm missing something just can't figure out what it is.
I have the following component:

```
const SearchComponent = (props) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  const searchInputHandler = e => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    setSearchValue(inputValue);
    console.log(searchValue);
    // filterData(searchValue, props)
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Col className="col-sm-6" style={styles.flex}>
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={e => searchInputHandler(e)}
          value={searchValue}
          />
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
          <Button style={styles.inputButton} color="info">Clear</Button>
        </InputGroupAddon>
      </InputGroup>
    </Col>
    </>
  )
};
```

in the above component the initial value of my Input is ' '.  When I type any letter let's say a "t".

I would expect that searchValue would = "t" since I am running setSearchValue(inputValue) in my method.  However when I type in "t" the state stays the same.  Only after I type it the second time then it would show ' t'.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous.

See [When is setState asynchronous?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous)

> Currently, setState is asynchronous inside event handlers.

[Why doesn’t React update this.state synchronously?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-doesnt-react-update-thisstate-synchronously)

> React intentionally “waits” until all components call setState() in their event handlers before starting to re-render. This boosts performance by avoiding unnecessary re-renders.

Therefore, logging `console.log(searchValue);` right after `setSearchValue(inputValue);` will log the value of `searchValue` in the **current render** (or "in the current scope").